# Searching data using Ajax in CakePHP

Tags: ajax, cakephp, search

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In one of my projects, I have to implement the `Searching` feture, using AJAX. Normally, this is working, but I want that the page won't reload, the result table will be immediately updated with the data.

This is the `Controller` code:

```
public function searchData(){
    $this->set(............);
    $this->set(............);
    $this->set(............);
    if($this->request->is('post')){
$this->layout='ajax';
$this->autoRender=false;
       if(!empty($data)){
          $data=$this->request->data;
          // Generating options
          .
          .
          .
          $result=$this->ModelName->find('all',$options);// "$options" is generated options
          if(!empty($result)){
$this->set(compact($result));
$this->set('_serialize',array('result'));
print_r(json_encode($result));
             $this->Session->setFlash("Searching Applicants Successful");
             $this->set('result',$result);
          }else
             $this->Session->setFlash("No data found");
       }else
          $this->Session->setFlash("You didn't give any info to search for");
    }
}
```

My `View` file(search_data.ctp) :

```
<h3>Search Result</h3>
<?php
    echo $this->form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('field1',array('type'=>'text,'div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('field2',array('type'=>'text,'div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('field3',array('type'=>'text,'div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('field4',array('type'=>'text,'div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Search');
    echo $this->Form->end();
<div id="searchResult">
<?php if(!empty($result)){?>
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
           <thead>
              <th>Field 1</th>
              <th>Field 2</th>
              <th>Field 3</th>
              <th>Field 4</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
<?php foreach($result as $applicant){?>
               <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $result['ModelName']['field1'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['ModelName']['field2'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['ModelName']['field3'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $result['ModelName']['field4'];?></td>
               </tr>
<?php }?>
           </tbody>
       </table>
<?php
     }else
        echo "No data found";
?>
</div>
```

Here, what I want is, when I submit the form, the "result" `div` will immediately appear, with the result data, organized in the table. I want to use `Ajax` here, so that users will get the result immediately, it'll improve the performance and user experience.

I've seen some youtube videos, where they load another page with the result, and shows that page in a `div` (it is called "success" `div` most of the time :) ), using `Ajax`. I can do it. But, I just want to do everything in 1 page, I don't want to use 2 pages to do it.

I tried this for ajax request and update my "result" `div`(in my `search_data.ctp` file) :

```
$this->Js->get('.search-form')->event('submit',$this->Js->request(array('controller'=>'cntrlr_name','action'=>'searchData'),array('async'=>true,'update'=>'#searchResult')));
```

And when I run the page, this is the output :

```
[{"Applicant":{"id":"3","name":"Name 2","email":"ssaha.316@gmail.com","mobile":"9082730572","contact_phone":"3465360980","office_phone":"2437845693","correspondence_address":"Correspondence Address 2","permanent_address":"Permanent Address 2","preferred_work_areas":"Field 1, Field 2, Field 3","created":"2014-05-31 18:22:17","modified":"2014-05-31 18:22:17"},"ApplicantAcademicQualification":[{"id":"2","applicant_id":"3","level":"Bachelor(Pass)","degree_title":"B.A.","passing_year":"1999","institution":"Institution 2","result":"4.2","major":"Bengali Literature","created":"2014-05-31 18:22:17","modified":"2014-05-31 18:22:17"}],"ApplicantEmploymentHistory":[{"id":"2","applicant_id":"3","employer":"Employer 2","position_held":"Position 2","industry":"Industry 2","department":"Department 2","major_responsibilities":"Responsibility 2","job_location":"Local","key_achievement":"Achievement 2","served_from":"1999-08-15","served_till":"2010-02-12","created":"2014-05-31 18:22:17","modified":"2014-05-31 18:22:17"}],"ApplicantOther":[{"id":"2","applicant_id":"3","academic_activities":"Academic Activities 2","non_academic_activities":"Non Academic Activities 2","main_reason_for_applying":"Reason 2","worked_before":"0","last_position":"","work_location_constraint":"1","ready_to_join_on":"2008-08-14","expected_salary":"30k+","created":"2014-05-31 18:22:17","modified":"2014-05-31 18:22:17"}],"ApplicantProfessionalQualification":[{"id":"2","applicant_id":"3","name_of_certificate":"Certificate 2","institute":"Institute 2","from":"2002-10-17","to":"2007-10-12","location":"Local Ins.","created":"2014-05-31 18:22:17","modified":"2014-05-31 18:22:17"}],"ApplicantTraining":[{"id":"2","applicant_id":"3","title":"Title 2","institute":"Institute 2","training_year":"1995","location":"In Company","created":"2014-05-31 18:22:17","modified":"2014-05-31 18:22:17"}]},{"Applicant":{"id":"2","name":"Name 1","email":"user1@email.com","mobile":"715414918934","contact_phone":"2357295090","office_phone":"083656987398","correspondence_address":"Address 1_1","permanent_address":"Address 1_2","preferred_work_areas":"Field 1, Field 2, Field 3","created":"2014-05-18 16:48:08","modified":"2014-05-18 17:20:12"},"ApplicantAcademicQualification":[{"id":"1","applicant_id":"2","level":"Secondary","degree_title":"S.S.C","passing_year":"2009","institution":"Institute 1","result":"4","major":"Science","created":"2014-05-18 16:48:08","modified":"2014-05-18 17:20:12"}],"ApplicantEmploymentHistory":[{"id":"1","applicant_id":"2","employer":"Employer 1","position_held":"Position 1","industry":"Industry 1","department":"Department 1","major_responsibilities":"Responsibilities 1","job_location":"Local","key_achievement":"Achievements 1","served_from":"2005-03-12","served_till":"2007-11-26","created":"2014-05-18 16:48:08","modified":"2014-05-18 17:20:12"}],"ApplicantOther":[{"id":"1","applicant_id":"2","academic_activities":"Academic Activities 1","non_academic_activities":"Non Academic Activities 1","main_reason_for_applying":"Reason 1","worked_before":"1","last_position":"Last Position 1","work_location_constraint":"1","ready_to_join_on":"2008-07-10","expected_salary":"20k-25k","created":"2014-05-18 16:48:08","modified":"2014-05-18 17:20:12"}],"ApplicantProfessionalQualification":[{"id":"1","applicant_id":"2","name_of_certificate":"Certificate 1","institute":"Institute 1","from":"2011-10-11","to":"2012-09-11","location":"Local Ins.","created":"2014-05-18 16:48:08","modified":"2014-05-18 17:20:12"}],"ApplicantTraining":[{"id":"1","applicant_id":"2","title":"Title 1","institute":"Institute 1","training_year":"2013","location":"Local Ins.","created":"2014-05-18 16:48:08","modified":"2014-05-18 17:20:12"}]}]
```

Is it possible ? How can I do it ? Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- Your search method [returns data as JSON](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).
- Then on your page loop data in [jquery template](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template).

Here is an [example](http://codepb.github.io/jquery-template/Examples/index.html) of how to use jQuery templates, and [here](http://codepb.github.io/jquery-template/index.html) it's documentation

[Here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-P969.html) is another approach

**UPDATE**

simple return json results from your search method:

```
public function searchData(){
$this -> layout = 'ajax';
$this -> autoRender = false;
if($this->request->is('post')){
   if(!empty($data)){
      $data=$this->request->data;
      // Generating options
      ...
      $result = $this->ModelName->find('all',$options);// "$options" is generated options
      $this -> set(compact($result));
      $this -> set('_serialize',array('result'));
      echo json_encode($result);
    }
  }
}
```

Use and loop JSON results data

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you give me a little more description ? How can I return data in JSON ? Then, how I can I use the jquery template ? @Salines

Comment: Actually, I am kind a new in this, that's why asking for more information. Please help me. :) @Salines

Comment: Well, I am trying to understand the example :) @Salines

Comment: It's a good way to learn. For better understanding, here are tuturials  https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jquery+template+tutorial

Comment: I thought there is an easier way to do this, cz doing this using another page is easy. Do you know any easier way ? Does CakePHP provide anything for this ? @Salines

Comment: I show you the easy way to return JSON data from your search method. Use data and loop in your jquery scripts.

Comment: I saw your updated answer. Here, you are showing the data in the controller function, but I don't know yet how to show this data in the view file(with customization). Can you please tell me how do I show this data(just return the data) in the view file ? By the way, thanks a lot for your help :) .@Salines

Comment: Hi, I've just edited my question, here I tried using AJAX request in CakePHP, but it didn't work, and I mentioned it in my question. Can you please have a look at it and help me, let me know what is my fault ? Thanks :) @Salines

Comment: If you use a function that I wrote in answer, show me how it looks your json output after clicking submit. For this test does not use ajax post. Also, to test your jquery functions used firefox firebug or chrome web developer tools extensions.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the question again ?I've just edited my question. Now, I added the json code(according to your function) and the output when I run the page. Here, I used the "ajax" layout when I get the "POST" request, cz I need that the will be rendered normally at first. It should use ajax layout after I submit the form. Please have a look at it and let me know what should I do now. I think, I just need to output the result array correctly, that's it, nothing else. @Salines

Answer (score 1):

update your function searchData:

```
  public function searchData(){
      //just empty for showing the form only
  }
```

add ajax function:

```
  public function ajax_search(){
   $this->layout="ajax";
   $result = array();
   $field1 = $_POST["field1"];
   $field2 = $_POST["field2"];
   $field3 = $_POST["field3"];
   $field4 = $_POST["field4"];
   if( $field1 &&  $field2 &&  $field3  &&  $field4 ){ //change this depending on your queries
         $data=$this->request->data;
         // Generating options
         .
         .
         .
         $result=$this->ModelName->find('all',$options);// "$options" is generated option
    }
    $this->set("result", $result);
   }
```

add view ajax_search.ctp:

```
  <?php if($result):?>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
             <th>Field 1</th>
             <th>Field 2</th>
             <th>Field 3</th>
             <th>Field 4</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
         <?php foreach($result as $applicant){?>
              <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $result['ModelName']['field1'];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['ModelName']['field2'];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['ModelName']['field3'];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $result['ModelName']['field4'];?></td>
              </tr>
          <?php }?>
          </tbody>
      </table>
   <?php else:?>
      No results.
  <?php endif;?>
```

update you searchData.ctp:

```
 <h3>Search Result</h3>
 <?php
    echo $this->Form->create("Search",array("default"=>false, "id"=>"SearchForm"));
    echo $this->Form->input('field1',array('type'=>'text,'div'=>false));
     echo $this->Form->input('field2',array('type'=>'text,'div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('field3',array('type'=>'text,'div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('field4',array('type'=>'text,'div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Search');
   echo $this->Form->end();
   <div class="result">
;?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on('submit','#SearchForm',function(){
     $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data:{
      field1:$("#SearchField1").val, // the ids of your input or you can modify these if you have assigned ids to the input
         field2:$("#SearchField2").val,
         field3:$("#SearchField3").val,
         field4:$("#SearchField4").val
  },
      beforeSend: function(){
        $("#result").html("loading...");
      }
  url: "<?php echo $this->base;?>/{insert your controller name here}/ajax_search/",
  success:function(data) {
         $("#result").html(data);
      }
   });              
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, its an easier way, I just wanted to do it in the same page, in 1 page. I just wanted not to use the "ajax_search" page, I wanted to return the result in the same page using ajax. By the way, thanks a lot for your help. I'll use this if I don't find any better way. Thanks :) .@zynder

Comment: Hi, I've just edited my question, here I tried using AJAX request in CakePHP, but it didn't work, and I mentioned it in my question. Can you please have a look at it and help me, let me know what is my fault ? Thanks :) @zynder